# Parameter -RoomList cannot be found

Tags: powershell, outlook, microsoft-teams, o365security-compliance

I am trying to create new room distribution list in O365 for my company via PowerShell.

I want to list those rooms in MS Teams so I can book via Teams client

From what I learned, the steps are pretty straightforward

1. Create new distribution list with room mailboxes as members

`New-DistributionGroup -Name "ShRooms" -Members room1@contoso.com,room2contoso.com`

2. Set the group as RoomList

`Set-DistributionGroup -Identity "ShRooms" -RoomList`

But instead of some positive result, I got this:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'RoomList'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-DistributionGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Set-DistributionGroup
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

I tried

`(GET-Command Set-DistributionGroup).parameters`

and got

```
Key                                    Value
---                                    -----
WindowsEmailAddress                    System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
RejectMessagesFromSendersOrMembers     System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers        System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute10                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ModerationEnabled                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ExtensionCustomAttribute4              System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
Identity                               System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute8                       System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
DisplayName                            System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
Confirm                                System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute3                       System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
Name                                   System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute5                       System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ReportToManagerEnabled                 System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute7                       System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
BypassModerationFromSendersOrMembers   System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
PipelineVariable                       System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ExtensionCustomAttribute2              System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
RejectMessagesFrom                     System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
WarningVariable                        System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute6                       System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
SendOofMessageToOriginatorEnabled      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute1                       System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ErrorAction                            System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
Verbose                                System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ExtensionCustomAttribute3              System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute9                       System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ErrorVariable                          System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ModeratedBy                            System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute14                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
MailTip                                System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
Debug                                  System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
SimpleDisplayName                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
PrimarySmtpAddress                     System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom                 System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
MailTipTranslations                    System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute15                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
WhatIf                                 System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ReportToOriginatorEnabled              System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
OutVariable                            System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ExtensionCustomAttribute1              System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
RejectMessagesFromDLMembers            System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ExtensionCustomAttribute5              System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
MemberJoinRestriction                  System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute4                       System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
InformationVariable                    System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
Alias                                  System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
ManagedBy                              System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
GrantSendOnBehalfTo                    System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute2                       System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute13                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
SendModerationNotifications            System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
OutBuffer                              System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute11                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
EmailAddresses                         System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
InformationAction                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
CustomAttribute12                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
WarningAction                          System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
AsJob                                  System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
```

So this probably means that there really is not `-RoomList` parameter present, but from what I learned in documentation, it should be (we are running our company O365 in Europe, no special set-up)

Hope somebody can tell me how to change that distribution list. Thx

Comment: If I connect to Exchange Online using `Connect-EXOPssession`, I see `Set-DistributionGroup` with that parameter available.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Sadly, I tried to connect using Connect-EXOPssession, but the parameters did not change

Comment: Could you please try to run this command New-Distributiongroup -Name 'Room List Name' -RoomList,  Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity 'Room List Name' -Member RoomName@gmail.com, Get-Content | Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity 'Room List Name'?

Comment: I think you don't have enough permissions. I experienced the same after I logged in under tenant admin(the minimum required permissions definitely lower) it works perfectly :)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/room-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019#what-do-you-need-to-know-before-you-begin